# How to store device tokens in database

Tags: database, apple-push-notifications, token, device

I need to store device tokens for all the devices which have been registered with APNs for a particular application. What is the recommended table structure to store device tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any such recommended table structure for storing it, it all depends upon ur application server usage.
But you can store it against the device IMEI so that it can be uniquely identified.
Fields could be likewise:
IMEI | PUSH token | Last sent msg | TimeStamp etc